# Atomically Delete Database Entities and Files

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfilemanager

Let's say we have a Core Data entity `Image`, which has a property `url` storing the file system URL to the actual image file. We can implement a delete function like this:

```
func deleteImage(_ image: Image) {
    do {
        let url = image.url
        delete(image)
        try save()
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
    } catch {
        rollback()
    }
}
```

- If both `save()` and `removeItem(at:)` are succeed, the operation is succeed.
- If `save()` is failed, the database will rollback to its original state.
- **However, if `save()` is succeed but `removeItem(at:)` is failed, orphan files are left in the file system.**

Is there a way to make `deleteImage()` atomic, without involving a separate process checking and removing orphan files periodically?

-

It is possible to use `isDeletableFile(atPath:)`, but still not 100% reliable.

> `func isDeletableFile(atPath path: String) -> Bool`
>
> Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the file system or a particular file on the file system is not recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior or race conditions. It's far better to attempt an operation (such as loading a file or creating a directory), check for errors, and handle those errors gracefully than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation will succeed.

Comment: Why are you going to save something before making a delete? Anyway, you can use "guard" for save():
guard try save() else {
throw "throw error here"
}
and then try to delete an image

Comment: Core Data requires you to call `save()` to actually delete entities from the database. Also using `guard` won't help with situation 3.

Answer (score 0):

A really atomic delete is very difficult to achieve, but you can improve the stability of the code considerably if you change the order of the statements a little bit:

1. Delete the image in the database.
2. If successful, move the file to a temporary folder.
3. If successful, commit.
4. On success delete the file in the temporary folder, else move the file back to it's original location.

If operations 1 or 2 are not successful than rollback. The first part of 4 is not really necessary, and you can or should clean the temporary folder at certain points (e.g. program start, returning from background). The else part of 4 may fail in some rare situations which leads to an inconsistent state.

A more complex change can lead to an atomic delete. You do not delete your objects, but only mark them as deleted. A second step deletes first the file (if it exists) and than the entity. You can apply this second step immediately after each deletion, and at certain other points. The disadvantage of this solution is it complexity because you have to take the deleted objects into account with every data access.